# из-за подгрузки frame окна - страница показывается не полностью

Tags: javascript, iframe

я пытаюсь понять, как мне переопределить размер страницы через время..

что происходит:
в моб. приложении подгружается страница, внутри которой есть iframe, который подгружается через 1-2 секунды.
Но моб. приложение фиксирует высоту без iframe, потом он появляется, а высота страницы не обновляется

попробовал так, но не помогло

```
<script>
    setTimeout(function(){
   document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.height='100%';
}, 1000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Задай фиксированную высоту для iframe

Comment: а он появляется через скрипт, в таком случае можно заранее задать?

Comment: @DANILA помести его в div и задай для div фиксированную высоту. Этот div пропиши заранее в html. Для iframe дай значения height: 100%; и все

Comment: понял, спасибки, щас попробую